# Prolog search element in a list and add Symbol

Tags: list, numbers, prolog

I have, for example this number list:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].
```

I have to search a number for example `7` and insert `"$"` BEFORE and AFTER `7`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,$,7,$,8,9,10].
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use swi prolog, you could use a replace predicate (found in other stack overflow questions), combined with a flatten operator on a list:

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

replace(_, _, [], []).
replace(O, R, [O|T], [R|T2]) :- replace(O, R, T, T2).
replace(O, R, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- H \= O, replace(O, R, T, T2).
```

now:

```
replace(1,[$,1,$],[4,3,2,1],NewList),flatten(NewList,FlattendList).
NewList = [4, 3, 2, [$, 1, $]],
FlattendList = [4, 3, 2, $, 1, $] ;
```

Of course you can build pretty predicate for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i've understood, but now i've another little problem:
If i have a list like this:

    [4, 3, 1, $, 1, $, $, 2, $, 4, $, $, 5, $]

How can i delete duplicate:

    $$

In order to had this:

    [4, 3, 1, $, 1, $, 2, $, 4, $, 5, $]

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Last thing, how can i merge two part of the same list: [1,2,3,4,$,5,$,5,$,6,7] => [1,2,3,4,$,5,5,$,6,7]? Thanks.